# How to know version of MKL used by numpy in python anaconda distributive?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, intel-mkl

How to know version of MKL used by numpy in python anaconda distributive from python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found method mkl.get_version_info():

```
import mkl
mkl.get_version_string()
```

console:

```
'Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.0 Product Build 20180829 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications'
```

Comment: Which package does mkl come from? I'm not sure if this would say whether your numpy was built with or without mkl.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: there is another method to check the version of mkl w/o code modification. You need to set/export environment variable `MKL_VERBOSE=1` ( by default this variable is not set) and all mkl's functions will print version and many debug info.

Comment: yes, the method returns MKL version and other additional information, but only to console.